# How to flash scatter-based stock ROM through custom recovery

Tags: rom-flashing, stock-rom

I'm using a Karbonn A52+ (Mediatek 6572) running on Android 4.2.2 (stock ROM) with root access, unlocked bootloader and Clockwork Mod Custom Recovery installed.

I have a 4.4 Kitkat stock ROM for my device which is a scatter-based ROM and needs to be flashed through SP Flash Tool. However, for some reasons I'm unable to use SP Flash Tool.

So is there any method which can allow me to flash that ROM through CWM Recovery? I have experience in flashing custom ROMs through recovery, but never flashed a stock ROM using recovery. Can I convert that ROM which needs to be flashed using SP Flash Tool to a ROM which can be flashed through custom Recovery?

P.S. The 4.4 ROM which I want to flash is known to have some bugs, like:

1. It locks my bootloader.
2. It disallows me to boot into recovery using the hardware method, i.e. <kbd>Power</kbd> button + <kbd>Volume Up</kbd> Button. The only way to get into recovery would be either through ADB or through a Reboot Manager from Play Store.

Comment: The files in a scatter based ROM are mainly image files so you should be able to flash them using fastboot, provided that you know the names of the partitions to flash. In any case, you need to make a Recovery flashable zip out of that scatter-ROM and that's something you need to search on web. // Better is to find out a Recovery flashable stock ROM zip for your device.

Comment: @Firelord, can you suggest whether this method would be safe for me?
http://www.gizbeat.com/7260/flash-rom-upgrade-firmware-without-losing-user-data-cache/

Comment: But why link that method now? The content in the link depends upon SP Flash Tools but you mentioned in the question that you're unable to use that tool.

Comment: I have few doubts in the method which the link provides:
For the scatter file: It asks me to use the scatter file which was made for the ROM which I'm currently using, and that is Jelly Bean
But that scatter file has a different preloader name (as the preloader in my current ROM is for jelly bean and the new one is for kitkat) so I hope if I flash the KitKat ROM without flashing the preloader it won't harm my device?

Comment: I was unable to use SP Flash Tool coz I got an error saying "PMT changed for the ROM: It must be downloaded" and some google search suggested that error was due to some scatter file issue